# Multiline replace using sed

Tags: bash, sed, makefile, sequelize.js

Due to a bug in a utility, I need to find a series of lines and alter them.  I've been trying to use `sed` but can't figure out the syntax on macOS.

Essentially, I need to find the following lines:

```
type: DataTypes.DATE,
allowNull: true,
primaryKey: true
```

... and alter the last two lines IF this sequence exists:

```
type: DataTypes.DATE,
allowNull: true
```

The entire file originally looks like this:

```
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('product', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    _u: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    _v: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    _d: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'product'
  });
};
```

Comment: Do you need to use sed or could you use something else like perl which is almost as compact for regex?

Comment: At this point, I don't care.  I've tried both without success.  I'm guessing I'm screwing up the regex.

Comment: `sed` comes with a stack buffer that you can use for your problem, but in general `sed` is difficult to use for multi-line problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiline pattern matching in sed you're going to need to use the `N` command to pull in the next line into a pattern space.  If I understand your requirements, something like this should to the trick:

```
$ cat multiline-replace.sed 
/type: DataTypes.DATE,/{N
    /allowNull: true/{N  
       /primaryKey: true/{
         s/allowNull: true/why would I allow this?/
         s/primaryKey: true/shmimaryKey: false/
       }      
    }
}
```

The idea is that when `/type: DataTypes.DATE,/` matches, you read the next line into the patterns space (with scope delimited by {}.  Do the same thing on your `allowNull: true` line and your `primaryKey: true` line.  Then you've got the three lines in the pattern space and you can do the modifications you want to do to them. `s/pattern/replacement/`.

I copied your input into the file `input` then I tested it against this program:

```
$ cat input | sed -f multiline-replace.sed 
/* jshint indent: 2 */

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('product', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    _u: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: 'user',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    _v: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    _d: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      why would I allow this?,
      shmimaryKey: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'product'
  });
};
$
```

See also this post on Unix stack exchanges which gives more detail about the sed commands (also `man sed` is your friend): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string#26290

Comment: Any chance you can use your god-like powers on this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010387/use-sed-file-to-replace-invalid-json-based-on-line-prefix

Comment: Haha, I'll take a look.  But, fwiw, when you're doing complicated, multi-line stuff, it's usually easier to just upgrade to a fully-featured (and high level) programming language (python or perl).  Cheers!

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Come to think of it, I'm just replacing a line that will only occur once.  Forget I said anything.  You're still THE man.

Answer (score -1):

After using sed for a while, and never remembering the syntax, I created a utility, called [`file-line-replacer`](https://github.com/FredLackey/file-line-replacer), to solve the issue once and for all.  Although I already selected the "correct" answer *years* ago, I'm posting it here for completeness.  Here are the steps I use.

First, install it (I prefer installing it globally)...

`npm i -g file-line-replacer`

... then, simply run one command (this example was for for the sequelize issue above) ...

```
file-line-replacer \
  --search-dir "/Users/flackey/my-project/src/data/models" \
  --backup-dir "/Users/flackey/my-project/_backup" \
  --old-lines "allowNull: false,|primaryKey: true" \
  --new-lines "autoIncrement: true,|primaryKey: true" \
  --overwrite
```

The above command will tweak each file, where the old lines exist, and create a backup before it is modified.